# Find the matching NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm using a plist structured as an array with dictionaries to populate my app. The plist is stored in the bundle. I have made some changes in some strings in some of the dictionaries (like spelling corrections).

`appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` calls `copyPlist` to copy the plist to documents directory if it doesn't exist. So if the plist does exist, I need to check some strings in every dictionary for changes, and replace these strings.

I made two `NSMutableArrays`:

```
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: documentsDirectoryPath]) {
NSMutableArray *newObjectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:documentsDirectoryPath];
NSMutableArray *oldObjectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:bundlePath];

//Then arrange the dictionaries that match so some their strings can be compared to each other.
}
```

How can I arrange the matching `NSDictionaries` so some of their strings can be compared? The `Name` string is unchanged, so this could be used to recognize a match.

Code examples or reference to useful a tutorial or sample codes would be great, as my own research hasn't lead to anything useful and I really need to correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plist can be read directly into a dictionary like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

If you do this for two plists, you can update one of them using matching keys from the other like this:

```
- (void)updateDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictA withMatchingKeysFrom:(NSDictionary *)dictB {

    // go through all the keys in dictA, looking for cases where dictB contains the same key
    // if it does, dictB will have a non-nil value.  use that value to modify dictA

    for (NSString *keyA in [dictA allKeys]) {
        id valueB = [dictB valueForKey:keyA];
        if (valueB) {
            [dictA setValue:valueB forKey:keyA];
        }
    }
}
```

Before you start, you'll want to make the dictionary that's getting updated mutable, like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableDictionary *dictA = [dict mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Exellent answer, exactly what I wanted! Thank you.